# Unable to create a table automatically and insert records using spring and hibernate integration

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am new to spring and trying to integrate hibernate with spring.
I am using MySql database and trying to insert a record using saveOrUpdate() method.

So the program is firing a sql query for creating table(as it should).

But the issue is, even though it is firing a query for 'create table', the table is not being created in database.
Also, if the table is created manually in the database and then try to insert the record, it does nothing.

I have tried using save() and persist() method instead of saveOrUpdate(), but it took me nowhere.

This is the main class.
Values of the bean class(Employee) has been set in order to insert a record.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    ApplicationContext context=new 
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("sphb.xml");
    EmployeeDAO edao=(EmployeeDAO) context.getBean("d");
    Employee e=new Employee();
    e.setId(1);
    e.setName("sourav");
    e.setSalary(100000);
    edao.saveEmployee(e);
}
```

This is the bean class:-
    public class Employee 
    {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    //getters and setters
    }

This is the xml file containing all the config.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"> 
    </property>  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"></property>  
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="1234"></property>  
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

    <property name="mappingResources">  
    <list>  
    <value>mapping.hbm.xml</value>  
    </list>  
    </property>  

    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop 
            key 
            ="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

        </props>  
    </property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="template" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
    <property name="checkWriteOperations" value="false"></property>
    </bean>  

    <bean id="d" class="demo.sphbIntegrate.EmployeeDAO">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

This is the DAO class:-

```
public class EmployeeDAO 
{
    HibernateTemplate template;

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void saveEmployee(Employee e) 
    {
    template.saveOrUpdate(e);
    }
}
```

Output when table is not created manually in database:-

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for 
more info.
**Hibernate: create table employee (id integer not null, name varchar(255), 
salary integer, primary key (id)) type=MyISAM
Hibernate: select employee_.id, employee_.name as name2_0_, 
employee_.salary as salary3_0_ from employee employee_ where employee_.id=?
Exception in thread "main" 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not 
extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet**
at org. springframework. orm. hibernate5. SessionFactoryUtils. 
convertHibernateAccessException (SessionFactoryUtils.java:230)
at org. springframework. orm. hibernate5. HibernateTemplate. doExecute 
(HibernateTemplate.java:387)
and 15 more...
```

Output when table is created manually:-

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for 
more info.
**Hibernate: select employee_.id, employee_.name as name2_0_, 
employee_.salary as salary3_0_ from employee employee_ where employee_.id=?**
```

Just this select query is executed, not insert one.

Comment: have you checked that the db user you are using to connect to database has sufficient permissions (CREATE TABLE)?

Comment: @Miha Jamsek  Yes, I have seen to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work by adding a  which uses annotation for managing transactions

```html
 <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
      </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

Also added setter for sessionFactory and used annotation for transaction and gave the rights for write operation.

```html
public class EmployeeDAO 
{
    HibernateTemplate template;

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
 this.template=new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void saveEmployee(Employee e) 
    {
 template.saveOrUpdate(e);
    }
}
```